# How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` do not show the newest kernel.

How can I install 3.16 kernel on 14.04?

Comment: It's not been released as yet for 14.04: "It’s out, which means you want it. Well, hold your horses. Linux 3.16 is likely to form the basis of the Ubuntu Linux Kernel in 14.10, which is due later this year. The 14.10 kernel will also be provided to LTS users through a point release update shortly after.

If you’re impatient and — most importantly — skilled enough, you can install Linux 3.16 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the corresponding installers for your system listed in the Mainline kernel archive maintained by Canonical." http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/linux-kernel-3-16-changes-drivers

Comment: Did you not see my answer below?

Comment: What about it? We're addressing different things. You've answered the question by providing a method to install the newest kernel. I've commented on why his first attempt at installing it didn't work.

Comment: Lol there was never a first attempt. Look at OP and answerer. This is here for anyone who might want to upgrade to the latest and doesn't know how

Comment: :P My bad guy. Maybe reword your original question to make it clear you're posting a general guide here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install the latest kernel you can always visit [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) to see what's going on.

To install the latest 3.16 kernel all you need to do is:

```
cd /tmp
```

for 32bit:

```
wget \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_i386.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_all.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_i386.deb
```

for 64bit:

```
wget \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_all.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb
```

then, making sure you have no other `.deb`s in  `/tmp`

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If wanted to manually add the PPA to `sources.list` and its key, what do I need to do?

Comment: How can you revert back to the current version of the kernel?

Comment: For most users, the `generic` kernel will work fine, only use `lowlatency` if you need it. Overall performance will be worse on some systems if you use `lowlatency`.

Comment: all in one!!! 32Bit ```cd /tmp && wget \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_i386.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_all.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i *.deb && sudo reboot ```

Comment: all in one!!! 64Bit ```cd /tmp && wget \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-generic_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-headers-3.16.0-031600_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_all.deb \
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-utopic/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600.201408031935_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i *.deb && sudo reboot ```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure most people could've easily combined all of that into one, but that wasn't the purpose..

Comment: can you install multiple kernels in this manner and choose which one to use at boot?

Answer (score 24):

Now that 14.10 has been released, there is an easier and better way to get 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
```

This package will always depend on the latest 3.16 image available.
(This method may not have been ready at the time of this article.)

Comment: +1. This is a supported kernel backport in the hardware-enablement programme of Ubuntu LTS. More information here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack As described on that page, make sure though, to also install the backported Xorg updates to prevent issues with your graphics/X stack (not available yet at the time of writing).

Comment: seems to have the support right now `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`

Comment: As a reference, it's all described here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Adding on to @ThiagoMacedo 's comment, there is libwayland missing. This should be `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic`.

Answer (score 4):

I do recommend using the `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` or whatever newer made available for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Try avoid mixing release repositories, it may break things.

If `linux-image-generic-lts-$(lsb_release -sc)` is NOT new enough for you, try the Ubuntu Kernel mainline archive (manually download and install) http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

> NOTE: the drawback of using mainline kernel is that you may not be able to compile drivers or things like VirtualBox won't work with the cutting edge kernel. Last but not least, ksplice (uptrack) won't work with mainline kernels anyway (uptrack does support newer kernel from later releases on current LTS).

Answer (score 0):

I started with Ubuntu 14.04.1 (kernel 3.13) and wanted to get only the 3.16 kernel and HWE stack. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic
```

Add the kernel headers if you want too by adding `linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic` to the above command.

Or just download the 14.04.2 image from [Ubuntu release archives](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/). XD