# How can I install Ubuntu 14.10's kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: kernel

I have been able to download kernel 3.16 from the ubuntu mainline kernel repository . However, I am more interested to know if the kernel shipped by default with Ubuntu 14.10 can be installed in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Please note, the mainline 3.16 kernel is a little different from the one shipped with Ubuntu 14.10 and I am interested  in the later. And, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04) is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add Utopic main repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main"
   ```
2. Update package lists

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Update kernel meta package to install last version

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic
   ```
4. Remove repository, to avoid any harmful update of other packages

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main"
   ```
5. Update package lists

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Tested on:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux machine 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~$ lsb_release -rc
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**Note:**

To update kernel follow same steps, only use update repository instead:

```
"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-updates main"
```

In case you want only security updates, use:

```
"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main"
```

Comment: Nice! It worked!

Comment: Note that you won't be getting kernel updates afterwards!

Comment: @VilmantasBaranauskas, yep, that's right. it's needed to run same steps to update kernel manually.

Comment: @Ubuntuser I suggest that you don't always run the newer kernels on 14.04, you're going to run into issues such as hardware driver failures potentially.  The security fixes for the issues fixed in later kernels usually end up in the LTS kernel, the kernel and security teams are pretty decent at keeping up to date with those.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, I installed Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer to upgrade the last Kernel as 5.8.14, and now I followed your steps to set up the Ubuntu's default as 5.4.0.48.52 but after reboot, it's till running the Kernel 5.8.14. How can I set up to run the Ubuntu's default about Kernel?

Comment: @luisito_36 You can set older kernel as default by following the instructions in this post: https://askubuntu.com/q/216398/26246

Comment: @user.dz Thank you so much! It worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
```

This is from:
[How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04)