# Support for Kworld UB435-Q V3 TV Stick

Tags: mythtv, tv-tuner

I am trying to set up a small Home Theatre PC, based on Ubuntu (14.04), where I'm planning to run MythTV.

I've chosen the KWorld UB435-Q because of price, and have hit a wall as it seems many others have.
I verified mine is a V3. [This post on linuxtv.org](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/KWorld_UB435-Q_USB_ATSC_TV_Stick) says the V3 only works on a USB3 interface. Well, that is not what the package spec says... But of course my box is USB 2.0 only.

Now the folks at LinuxTV [seem to have done some work on that V3 device](http://git.linuxtv.org/cgit.cgi/mchehab/experimental-old.git/log/?h=ub435q_v3)

From the comments, the "patch" has been verified on ATSC signals (8VSB).

What would it take to have that patch available on a Ubuntu build ? Short of me rebuilding the kernel...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work...

[This page at linuxtv.org](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ATSC_USB_Devices) informs that this KWorld UB435-Q V3 is supported in Kernel 3.16.

I updated my box (Ubuntu 14.04) to use Kernel 3.16 (explained at [How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04)), much easier than trying to recompile the V4L library with the updated driver.

Once this got done, the device is recognized (expected), and able to scan. I have now my MythTV setup locking all ATSC channels.
My box is a Gygabyte Brix GB-BXBT-2807. It has 1 USB 3.0 and 2 USB 2.0. Just by chance, My first try had the tuner on the USB3 slot -> that works fine.

I then moved the tuner to one of the USB2 slots, detected fine, went through the whole scan & able to tune just fine.

So, great little inexpensive tuner.