# what is the best way to upgrade my kernel version?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a 3.17.4 kernel. i want to know if i should purge my installed kernel and install a new one or apply a patch to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connected to the internet, the fastest way to upgrade your kernel is to perform a system update, which is ordinarily automated but you can pre-empt the automated update if the matter is that urgent.  Simply open the Update Manager and click on Check.

Update:  I was very curious why anyone would be interested in forcing such an upgrade or if there were a problem preventing the distribution of such an update.  Given some of the complaints I've been reading it wouldn't have surprised me to discover that the latest kernel had been distributed and disabled the systems which received it.  Nobody would want that!

So I've been reading about the ways to force an upgrade and how to get the very latest kernel and I've made some interesting discoveries.  [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04) which is now rather out of date gives a glimpse of how some people were updating their kernels just a few months ago.

Apparently Kernel 3.18 is currently released only in the Alpha release of Ubuntu 15.04, and I've also read that when 15.04 is fully released in April it is expected to come with Kernel 3.19.  I've been using Ubuntu for 9 years and until just the past few months I've never known Ubuntu to release anything before it was ready.  There seems to be a lot wrong with the current release, and that saddens me, but I only understand the symptoms, not the causes.  I'm more likely to continue to use 12.04LTS which is supported for 2.5 more years than to crowbar a new kernel into the mix.