# Ubuntu 15.04 freezing on shutdown/reset and having problem with AMD

Tags: drivers, ati, shutdown, freeze, 15.04

Having upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 my AMD graphics were still working but going to TTY, reset or shutdown would result in a freeze. The logs gave no real clues as to what is going on.

What I found so far:
- Selecting the 3.16 kernel in Grub prevents the freeze problem, but also prevents you from using fglrx
- Manually selecting the X.org driver (in Software & updates) prevents the freezing too, which makes me think it is purely driver related
- Changing /etc/default/grub to "quiet", as mentioned elsewhere for freezing issues on shutdown, does not change anything

What I would really like is to have the fglrx driver again, but I cannot tolerate a freeze everytime X is closing down. I will probably need to downgrade Ubuntu I guess, but if someone has an easier solution then please let me know.

Comment: I also updated to Ubuntu 15.04, my login screen freezes, key press or mouse does not work. If anyone could be an assistance that would be very useful.

Comment: As mentioned above, I decided to downgrade and would advise you to do the same. The fglrx is probably best tested on 14.4/10. I had a disappearing mouse issue as well like you, but it somehow went away after a few system freezes/reboots.

Comment: Add "additional Drivers" from the Ubuntu search icon. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bad English:)

Had same issue on my Lenovo laptop (intel hd video card) - had a freeze on restart/shutdown/sleep with Kubuntu 15.04. Same issue was reproduced with Ubuntu 14.04. In my case I even was unable to switch to tty.
On my laptop i had no fglrx, tried to modify grub config with all found "solutions" as reboot=bios & etc. - nothing helped.

Finally I fixed this on Kubuntu 15.04 by installing older kernel and headers (3.16.0 vs 3.19.6) + marked them as "hold" in aptitude + removed 3.19.6 kernel completely for now. Maybe you'll find other less aggressive solution but I needed fully working laptop asap.

Here're links to save you some googling time:)

Install 3.16.0 kernel (look at the accepted answer):
[How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Mark kernel and headers as "hold" to prevent upgrade (easy way through aptitude):

If you haven't got aptitude installed

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Run aptitude

```
sudo aptitude
```

Find installed kernel and headers under "Obsolete packages" section (don't remember exact name, sorry) and click "Package" -> "Hold" while selecting kernel or headers.

Remove 3.19.* kernel using Synaptics Package Manager:
http://connectwww.com/how-to-remove-old-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu-via-synaptic-package-manager/614/

Hope it will help someone.
In my case restart/shutdown and sleep are working fine now.

BR.