# Failed to install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I am trying to install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04. I was following `http://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04` instructions to install the kernel. I got these errors:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency (3.16.0-031600.201408031935) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-031600-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-031600-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libfuse2:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic (3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up iw (3.4-1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.127.12) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-38 (3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic (3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.38.30) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.38.30); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up os-prober (1.63ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
Setting up dmsetup (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
 linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
 linux-generic-lts-utopic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install 3.16 kernel to Ubuntu 14.04 this way.

This kernel has been included in trusty-updates repository.

Install it this way

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

for generic kernel, or

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency-lts-utopic
```

for lowlatency kernel.

The kernel will receive security updates automatically in normal update & upgrade process.

Comment: Still not working. Please see the updated question.